# How to regenerate config/application.rb in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, minitest, ruby-on-rails-4.2, rails-generate

Does Rails 4.2 provide a single command that regenerates `config/application.rb` in an existing application?

The reason I ask is imagine a Rails app is `rails new`-ed without the `--skip-test-unit` option.

Then at a much later date, this app is switched to RSpec. How can `config/application.rb` be regenerated as if the `--skip-test-unit` option had been supplied originally to `rails new ...`?

All this would effectively do is change the `require` statements near the top of `config/application.rb` file from:

```
require 'rails/all'
```

to:

```
require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but couldn't you just run `rails new <AppName> --skip-test-unit` to a new directory and copy `config/application.rb` to your existing application?

Comment: Thanks @iqnivek, yep, that'd work for sure and be a fine solution. Perhaps there's something that's an even more lightweight solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the existing `config/application.rb` and, in the directory *above* the project root, run `rails new ...` with the options you want, including the application directory name, and the `--skip-test-unit` option, **and** the `--skip` option, which makes `rails new ...` skip creating files that already exist:

```
# Inside your-rails-app/ directory:

# 1. Remove config/application.rb
rm config/application.rb

# 2. Move up one directory
cd ..

# 3. Regenerate rails application with the --skip
#    option, using the name of your-rails-app. The
#    --skip option will not generate files that
#    already exist.
#     
#    This assumes you have rails installed as a global
#    gem, of the version given in the command (version
#    x.y.z in this case, replace with the version of Rails
#    your app uses, e.g. 4.2.88):
rails _x.y.z_ new your-rails-app --skip --skip-test-unit

# 4. Run git status to see if any files were unexpectedly added
#    (for example the README.rdoc file will be created
#    if it did not exist).
git status

# 5. Clean up and commit the changes you want.
```

And that's it!